# play iphone audio at constant volume

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audioqueueservices

I am using AudioQueue Services to play audio in my app (AQPlayer borrowed from Speak Here) and I would like to know if it is possible to play the audio at a constant volume regardless of the iphone hardware volume.

Apple's phone.app keypad is an example of this, the tones play at the same volume regardless of your hardware volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't do that, people set their volume for a reason.

---

If you really think you must; an approach could *possibly* be to determine the hardware volume and preamp your sound by the required amount to receive the same volume. (Basically, if the hardware volume is at "5", and you want your sound to play at "8", you have to preamp your sound by "3".)

Comment: yeah I was considering doing it that way. My app has a phone keypad and I'm just trying to duplicate Apple's functionality as best I can since they've done a lot more usability studied that I ever could. Perhaps I'll leave it as-is.